# Running romex around switch box that is not being terminated to said switch box

Tags: wiring

Can I run a romex cable not going to a switch box around the switch box as long as it is stapled at both sides of switch box. From a vertical perspective

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can loop around a box provided you staple like you describe. I'd suggest having the cable not touch the box since someday the box may have to be removed and keeping the cable away from the box will prevent it getting damaged.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that would be fine per 2011 NEC Article 334 Nonmetallic-Sheathed Cable: Types NM (Romex), NMC, and NMS.

> *(emphasis mine)*
>
> ### 334.30 Securing and Supporting
>
> Non-metallic sheathed cable shall be supported and secured by staples,
>   cable ties, straps, hangers, or similar fittings designed and
>   installed so as not to damage the cable, at **intervals not exceeding
>   1.4 m (4.5 ft) and within 300mm (12 in.) of every outlet box, junction box, cabinet, or fitting**. Flat cables shall not be stapled on their
>   edge.

Even though it says *every* box, etc., it really means every box it enters/exits. So, assuming you follow the above you're good to go.